# Linking to a page, loading the page, and scrolling to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, settimeout

I have a site that is made up of a long homepage with a series of sections with separate IDs, and a blog with single posts as separate pages.

In the header there are menu items which, if a user is on the homepage, scroll down when clicked to the various panels using the IDs (#section-one, #section-two etc). This part is working nicely.

I've made a second menu for the single blog posts, which is basically the same but links to the various panels on the homepage (www.website.com/home/#section-one etc). My hope is to get these to scroll nicely too, so that when a user clicks, the homepage loads and then scrolls down to the right section.

I'm using the jQuery below to create the scroll effect. At the moment it uses `setTimeout` with a value of 0, and this is causing a problem - the scroll runs before the page is fully loaded, and stops in the wrong place. If I set the value of 'setTimeout' to a higher value it creates an ugly flash/pause when the homepage loads before the scroll runs.

Is there an alternative way of ordering things, so that the page loads, and the script waits until it has loaded completely before the animation fires?

Here is what I have so far:

```
var jump = function (e) {
if (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
} else {
    var target = location.hash;
}

$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 70
}, 1500, 'easeInOutCubic');

};

$('html, body').hide();

$(document).ready(function () {

$('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

if (location.hash) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
        jump();
    }, 0);

} else {
    $('html, body').show();
}

});
```

Comment: basically what @jfriend00 said. you should also reformat your code to get some answers, there is a missing curly brace!

Answer (score 0):

Why not start the animation inside the `$(document).ready()` callback so it doesn't start until the page has loaded?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 70}, 1500, 'easeInOutCubic');

});
```

Comment: Hi - thanks. When I try to rearrange it as you suggest, it dies completely. My understanding (which is probably sketchy) was that the variable 'jump' was running the animation inside `$(document).ready()`. Basically if I replace the if/else statement at the bottom with the animation, I get fatal errors from JSHint.

Comment: @SeanHawkridge - I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do so I can't offer the entire code, but the `target` variable has to be defined before you can use it in my above example.  You might get more help if you edited your question to explain the purpose/goal of your code (e.g. describe the behavior you're trying to achieve).

Comment: Sorry - I've edited it so it's hopefully a bit clearer now. I'm not looking for the entire code (I'd rather figure it out really), but if you were able to suggest the order in which you'd line things up that would be really helpful.